# Sum of first n fibonacci numbers haskell

Tags: haskell

I have tu calculate the sum of first n fibonacci numbers. fib function returns the nth fibonnaci number. But i dont know how to sum only the first n numbers ( n given number )

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib x = fib (x-1) + fib (x-2)

sumFib :: Int -> Int 
sumFib x = if x == fib x then x+fib x else fib x
```

Comment: Use a `fib` function that returns an infinite list of Fibonacci numbers (you can look it up online). Then use `sum (take n fib)`

Comment: This was answered here a few moments ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883290/how-does-haskell-compute-this-enormous-number-instantly/43893466#43893466

Comment: Do you know that `sum(Fib(1)..Fib(n)) = Fib(n+2) -1` ?

Comment: @Jonathan M: no I didn't know :) thank you

Comment: @4castle: I'm not allowed to used "take", I can use just Type A - Basic functions

Answer (score 2):

The first `n` numbers are `[1 .. n]`. For example, in ghci

```
Prelude> [1..7]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

You can [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) a function onto a list, applying that function to each element in the list, and returning the resulting list. For example

```
Prelude> double x = x+x
Prelude> map double [1..7]
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14]
```

You can do the same thing with `fib`, `map`ing it onto the first `n` numbers. If you want to do this for large `n` you'll need a more efficient implementation of `fib`.

You can [`sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) the elements in a list. For example

```
Prelude> sum [1,3,7]
11
```

If you put these three ideas together you can `sum` the result of `fib` for the first `n` numbers.

Comment: One last hint. `sumDouble n = sum (map double [1..n])`

Comment: I can't understand what sumDouble has to do with the sum of first n Fibonacci number. Anyway..thank you.

Comment: @Madalina It's a hint that Cirdec is providing to you. It's very close to what you want, except it uses a doubling function instead. Anything more than that would be giving the solution away. (This is why Cirdec wrote "one last hint".)

Comment: @chi: Thank you. it works but if I'm not allowed to use map, i defined map' instead. I will post the answer. Thanks again all

Answer (score 2):

Another good option would be to generate a lazy function to provide us a list of Fibonacci numbers indefinitely as many as we need. While we can achieve this with a lot of recursive trick, i believe the series generating function of Haskell, namely `unfoldr` is the ideal one. The following code will beautifully generate us a list of as many of Fibonacci numbers as wee need lazily.

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = unfoldr (\(f,s) -> Just (f,(s,f+s))) (0,1)
```

Now all we have to do is to get the sum of the Fibonacci numbers up to a given count. At this point the `take` function comes handy. `take` will take the first `n` items of a list. Then all we need to do is to apply the `sum` function to the resulting list.

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = unfoldr (\(f,s) -> Just (f,(s,f+s))) (0,1)

sumNFibs :: Int -> Integer
sumNFibs = sum . (flip take) fibs

*Main> sumNFibs 10
88
```

Comment: Thank you, thing is that I cannot use theese functions, I was supposed the basic ones.

Answer (score 1):

fib finds the n'th fibonacci number

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib x = fib (x-1) + fib (x-2)
```

map' is the implemantation of standard map function ( I wasn't allowed to use it)

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map' _ [] = []
map' f (x:xs) = f x : map' f xs
```

sumFib calculates the sum of first n fibonnaci numbers.

```
sumFib :: Int -> Int 
sumFib x = sum (map' fib [1..x])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @milo526 I've added some explanations

Answer (score 0):

```
fibo 0=0
fibo 1=1
fibo n=fibo(n-2)+fibo(n-1)
fibosum n=sum [fibo i | i<-[0..n-1]]
```

This code calculate the sum of first n fibonacci numbers. fibo function is calculate fibonacci numbers.